# MATLAB - printing graph with different output names

Tags: matlab

I have a MATLAB program that graphs some things and then outputs the graph to a file. If I run this program several times in the same directory, the file gets overwritten each time. How can I make it so the filename it outputs to changes...

I currently have this:

```
print -depsc myfigure
```

I have strings, rate and name, that I want to use, but can't get anything to work. If I can't use my strings, something random would be fine as well. Any way to do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: O wait! Just thought about it. I can run the MATLAB program and rename the file before running the program again in my script.

Still curious if this is possible though....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Name it with the current date and time:

```
print('-depsc2', ['prefix_' datestr(now, 30)])
```

run right now in PST, this creates a file called `prefix_20100220T200733.eps`. You can obviously change the prefix and/or the date format.

Answer (score 2):

You can add current time to your file name. For example:

```
m=magic(10);
fh=figure, surf(m);
currenttime= datestr(now,'MMSSFFF');
print(['-f',num2str(fh)],'-depsc',['outputFileName_',currenttime,'.eps']);
```

Answer (score 2):

This code checks if file exists, and if yes, adds a counter to its name.

```
filename = 'myfigure';
if exist([filename '.eps'],'file')
    k=1;
    while exist([filename '_' num2str(k) '.eps'], 'file')
        k=k+1;
    end
    filename = [filename '_' num2str(k)]);
end
print('-depsc', filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple. worked for me.

```
currenttime= datestr(now,'dd-mm-yy_HH:MM')
filename= ['graph' currenttime '.jpg']
print('-dpdf',filename)
```

Or any other file format you want to export. check print help.

Comment: How is this better than the answer that was accepted 4 years ago?

Comment: I did it. Found this post. So, shared my option there was no purpose of comparative adavantage for that.